# Convergence and Absolute Convergence of Arithmetic Mean of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, average

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ exists. Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ exist?

How about the converse?

My thoughts:

- I guess for the sequence $\{x_1,-x_1,x_2,-x_2,\ldots\}$ the converse doesn't necessarily hold.
- If I can show that the existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i 1\{x_i\geq 0\}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| 1\{x_i\leq 0\}$ exist, then the first part would hold. But I'm not sure this is true, I need to find a counterexample.

Comment: The natural observation is that $1/n\sum_ix_i\leq 1/n\sum_i|x_i|$. For the other question, observe that $\sum_i(-1)^i/i$ is a converging sequence by the Leibniz (alternating) criterion, but the absolute series doesn't converge.

Comment: @Cla: your second example is not relevant, because $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n1/i$ _does_ converge.

Comment: @Cla We have that $\sum_{i=1}^ni^{-1}\sim\log n$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence, $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^ni^{-1}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You were right. I forgot the $1/n$ multiplication term..sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample for the converse is $x_i = (-1)^i\sqrt i$.

Answer (score 0):

Another trivial counter example for the converse could be this:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i 1\{x_i\geq 0\}$ does not exist and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| 1\{x_i\leq 0\}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i 1\{x_i\geq 0\}$.

Comment: Does such a sequence exist?

Comment: I was thinking about $x_1, -x_1,x_2,-x_2,\ldots$ where $x_i\geq 0$ but this doesn't seem to work, good point..

Answer (score -1):

A bit of an explanation of Cla's hint: Consider 
$$
S^1_n = \frac{x_1 + \ldots x_n}{n} < \bigg| \frac{x_1 +\ldots x_n}{n} \bigg| <\frac{|x_1| +\ldots |x_n|}{n} = S^2_{n}
$$
by triangle inequality. Since we know that $S^2_n \to_n a< \infty$ and $S^1_n < S^2_n$, $S^1_n$ converges by comparison test.

Comment: "$S_n^1$ converges by the comparison test": not necessarily. You are claiming that if $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ are sequences (not series), and $v_n \to a$, and $|u_n| \le v_n$ for all $n$, then $u_n$ converges. Which is obviously false.

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something. What I meant was $S^1 <S^2 <a$ as $n \to \infty$ by comparison test because $x_k <|x_k|$.

Comment: But you claimed that $S_{1,n}$ converges! Where does that come from? (By $S_{1,n}$ I mean your $S_n^1$. Similarly, I suggest using $S_{2,n}$ instead of $S_n^2$.)

Comment: It is upper-bounded by $S^2_n$ which converges, so it converges by direct comparison test. Where's the mistake? I honestly don't understand.

Comment: For instance, the sequence $(0,1,0,1,.\ldots)$ is upper-bounded by $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$. But the second sequence converges, while the first sequence doesn't. The comparison test applies to series, not sequences.

Comment: I thought I was bounding the series, not the sequence.

Comment: The comparison test applies to _terms of a series_.